Formulating a LP model with 3 variables but there's a variable in the right-hand side of the inequality
I am having a pretty hard time formulating a model for this problem.
Problem: Three metals - copper, nickel, and zinc - are to be combined to produce an alloy suitable for a new 1 dollar coin being designed by the Bureau of Mint and Engraving. The costs per pound of the three metals are 0.60 dollars, 1.10 dollarsm and 0.85 dollars respectively. Chemical Analysis determines the following design requirements for the new alloy:

the percentage of the copper must not exceed 5 times the percentage of nickel.
the total percentage of nickel and zinc must exceed at least one-quarter the percentage of copper
the amount of zinc must not exceed 50%
copper must constitute at least 25% and nickel at least 30% of the new alloy.

The bureau would like to produce the new alloy at a minimum cost. Formulate LP model.
So here's how I formulated mine:
Let...
x = percentage for copper
y = percentage for nickel
z = percentage for zinc
C = cost to produce new alloy
min. C = 0.60x + 1.10y + 0.85z
subject to:

x ≤ 5y
y + z ≥ 0.25x
z ≤ 0.50
x ≥ 0.25
y ≥ 0.30
x + y + z = 1

The thing that I am confused here - since we aren't asked to solve or anything, just formulate LP model - should I try to solve the inequality so that there is no variable in the RHS of the equation? Based from what I did, especially on #1, the problem said the copper (x) must not exceed 5x the percentage of nickel (y). And yet since there is no given percentage of nickel, i put 5y there. So x ≤ 5y. This is not what a usual formulation looks like from all the times i have been practicing. This one has a variable after the inequality sign. However, my friend did something like this:
From ineq. 6: x + y + z = 1 ---> equate it to "y" only by transposing all the values to the other side
y = 1 - x - z ---> Substitute this to ineq. 1
ineq 1: x ≤ 5y
x ≤ 5 (1-x-z)
x ≤ 5 - 5x - 5z; transpose 5x and 5z to the other side so that a constant will just remain on the RHS
6x + 5z ≤ 5 ---> This is now her new inequality. Mine is x ≤ 5y
Which one is correct?

In general, there is nothing wrong in writing a constraint with that has variables on both sides. If you need the model to be in a particular "standard" format, either to facilitate entry in a software package or because an editor or instructor insists on it, you can rewrite $x \le 5y$ as $x-5y \le 0$ or $y+z \ge 0.25x$ as $0.25x - y - z \le 0.$
That said, I think the way you wrote the constraints maximizes ease of interpretation when someone reads your model. Also, as a matter of practice, I recommend against doing any algebra to eliminate variables, for three reasons. First, it tends to make the model harder for humans to read. Second, when using software, the solver will typically do some of this algebra for you, and it will be less error prone than a human. Third, for large models, contemporary solvers exploit sparsity of the constraint matrix. Doing algebraic reductions by hand tends to make the matrix smaller but also denser, and in terms of solution time the tradeoff is likely not in your favor.
